# Adding reviewers image from Google Places Review

Tags: json, google-api, google-places-api

I am currently using this jQuery plugin on my site to pull in a single user review from my Google Places account:

https://github.com/peledies/google-places (unmodified).

It works ok - however I need to extend the code to somehow also pull in and display the avatar/image of the reviewer that I'm pulling in.

```
   <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#google-reviews").googlePlaces({
                placeId: 'ChIJ_____....766FU3cfuE',
                render: ['reviews'],
                min_rating: 2,
                max_rows: 0,
                personsName: 'Jt D.'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I need to extend this to also include the avatar/image of the single review I am displaying.

I have found "profilePhotoUrl" is in the "reviewer" object in the JSON (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews) but I can't work out how to add that to the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of twiddling around, I found the following solution.

in the google-places.js, find the renderReviews function:

```
var renderReviews = function(reviews)
```

add this:

```
var img = reviews[i].profile_photo_url;
```

This returns the image stored in the review as a URL. You can then add it to the output within an img html tag:

```
if (name === plugin.settings.personsName) { html = html+" <img src="+ img +"> <div class='review-item'><div class='review-meta'><span class='review-author'>"+name+" | <span class='review-date'>"+date+"</span></div>"+stars+"<p class='review-text'>"+reviews[i].text+"</p></div>"
        }
```